# session not working in other controller in CI

Tags: php, codeigniter

I set session in login() controller where login user details is set in session. session library is autoload .

```
$data = $this->login_model->login_admin();

$this->session->set_userdata('UserLoggedInDetails',$data); //set login user details
```

when we do 
`var_dump($this->session->userdata('UserLoggedInDetails'));`//it prints all login user details in same controller

but when we do it in other controller or in same controller in other function-

```
var_dump($this->session->userdata('UserLoggedInDetails'));
```

it prints `array(0) { }`

my config file is-

```
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']  = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']  = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

I search all previous asked question like this but not solve this issue ...Please Help Me out .. 
All Suggestion are welcome . Thanks In Advance.

Comment: i think its var_dump($this->session->userdata('UserLoggedInDetails'));

Comment: How large is `$this->login_model->login_admin();` ? Because if you aren't storing sessions in DB, you might have a problem with holding large data in session afaik.

Comment: did you autoload the session class in autoload.php

Comment: @raheelshan yes I autoload the session

Comment: @venkatabandla its a typing mistake sorry

Comment: @goldenparrot its not that big . just loged in details like username,userid,email

Comment: If you didn't save session data in DB it will store in cookie........it's 4KB size limit.if ($this->sess_use_database === FALSE)
{
    $this->_set_cookie();
    return;
}

Comment: @venkatabandla yes this may be the case . can u please tell how to store session value in db .. I Never do this before .

Comment: Go through this link..........http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: @goldenparrot,@venkat,@raheel shan thanks every one , session data exceeds 4Kb and i m not saving data in db so it not work . thanks every one once again .

Comment: @ram I will write my comment as answer accept it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

update the following in your code it worked for me:

```
$config['sess_expiration']  = 8600;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you are not saving your session data in database. SO that going to save in cookie. We all know cookie has a limit 4KB. So save your session data array in data base like below tutorial shown in codeigniter user guide.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html